# stuck at shutdown: Running guests on default URI, no running guests

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have Ubuntu 22.04. Almost every time I shut down my PC, this happens.
I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, to switch to tty1, and then the system will immediately shutdown, but how to solve it permanently?

[image]